# Magento integration with ERB and POS system - Omar Bin Sulaiman

Tags: xml, magento

I am working on `magento` website, I want to integrate `magento` store with `POS system` which has the `XML file` of all `POS system` products.

Can any one help me to find the `POS system extension for magento with XML`.

Comment: be clear with your codes....

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.